# Maximum likelyhood of distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mse

$L$ is the upper limit of the sample distribution $[0, L]$ which is uniform and normal. how can I show that $L=\frac{(n+1)*max(X_i)}{n}$ is unbiased. and also has a lower MSE than MLE?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint for the first part of your question by telling you two useful results.

> **Theorem.**
>   Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with cumulative distribution function $F$.
>   Let $X=\max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$, and let $G$ be the cumulative distribution function of $X$.
>   Then
>   $$
> G(x) = F(x)^n
> $$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   Observe that
>   $$
> \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} \leq x
> $$
>   if and only if
>   $$
> X_1 \leq x, \ldots, X_n \leq x.
> $$
>   Using this observation, it follows that
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> G(x)
> &= P(X \leq x) \\
> &= P(X_1 \leq x, \ldots, X_n \leq x) \\
> &= P(X_1 \leq x) \cdots P(X_n \leq x) &&\text{(by independence)}\\
> &= \underbrace{F(x) \cdots F(x)}_{\text{$n$ times}}
> = F(x)^n.
> \end{aligned}
> $$

You can use this theorem to derive the cumulative distribution function of your estimator
$$
\frac{n+1}{n} \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}.
$$
Once you have the cumulative distribution function, you can compute the expectation using the following result.

> **Theorem**
>   Let $X$ be a *non-negative* absolutely continuous random variable with density $g$ and cumulative distribution function $G$.
>   Then
>   $$
> E[X]
> = \int_0^\infty (1 - G(x)) \, dx
> $$
>
> *Proof.*
>   By the definition of expectation and the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem of calculus, we have
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> E[X]
> &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} x g(x) \, dx &&\text{(definition of expectation)} \\
> &= \int_0^\infty x g(x) \, dx &&\text{(since $X$ is non-negative)} \\
> &= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^x 1 \, dy\right) g(x) \, dx \\
> &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^x g(x) \, dy \, dx \\
> &= \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty g(x) \, dx \, dy &&\text{(changing the order of integration)} \\
> &= \int_0^\infty P(X > y) \, dy \\
> &= \int_0^\infty (1 - G(y)) \, dy
> \end{aligned}
> $$

This theorem can be applied to compute the mean of your estimator to show that it is unbiased.